# I cannot pass messages to Apple via AeroGear Unified Push Server

Tags: ios, push-notification, aerogear

I can’t push to iOS. I get the following message:

```
Variant iOS Development has failed: Error sending payload to APNs server: java.net.ConnectException: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt (Connection refused)
```

I created and installed all certificates as described [here](https://aerogear.org/docs/unifiedpush/aerogear-push-ios/guides/) and everything runs fine. I can build the app and if I run it on my iPhone using Xcode, it asks me on first installation to accept notification. It seems to be perfect on the App-side.

In Aerogear Server under Variants appears my iPhone device and if I send a message I get this error.

I build the app with Cordova ionic and on Android it runs perfectly.

What does this error-message mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: is your certificate a development certificate or a production certificate? did you check the development radio button if you are using development certificate or production radio button if you are using production certificate?

Comment: I added both certificates and both didn't work. I also cross checked

Comment: But are you checking the right radio button depending on the certificate you upload? If you are running from Xcode, then use a Development certificate and check Development radio button

Comment: yes I checked the correct radio buttons

Comment: the server firewall allows all outgoing communication

Comment: Can you try to send the push from your computer using Pusher (https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) and your development certificate just to make sure that it's right? put the app in background before sending the push

Comment: I tried NWPusher and it worked. So the certificate seems valid

Comment: Then everything is ok on the app and certificate, the problem must be on the server, but you say that the firewall allows all outgoing communication, so I ran out of ideas.